# Logistic Regression in SAS

Tags: r, sas

I have the data below.

[image]

I wish to apply logistic regression. Here the response variable is the proportion of dead. Here is how I analyzed the data in R:

```
dose <- c(1.6907, 1.7242, 1.7552, 1.7842, 
          1.8113, 1.8369, 1.8610,1.8839)
total<- c(59,60,62,56,63,59,62,60)
dead<- c(6,13,18,28,52,53,61,60)
y <- dead/total

lineer.model <- glm(y ~ dose,family=binomial(link=logit), weights=total)
```

I want to do the exactly the same analysis in SAS. Can anyone please help me with that? Here is what i did in SAS, but thats not working. Any idea why

```
data beetle_data;
input dose total dead;
y = dead/total;
datalines;
1.6907  59 6
1.7242  60 13
1.7552  62 18
1.7842  56 28
1.8113  63 52
1.8369  59 53
1.8610  62 61
1.8839  60 60
;

proc logistic data=beetle_data;
model y =dose/link=logit dist=binomial;
run;
```

Comment: Answering the question "What have you tried?" in a convincing way would help make it into a specific question rather than overly broad.  Logistic regression is a standard routine, which can be found on the UCLA page or by searching the web.  If you encounter any problems we can then answer them, potentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this SAS document](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p264-26.pdf) (google "sas proc logistic binomial") it looks like this should do it:

```
proc genmod data=beetle;
model dead/total=dose / link=logit dist=binomial;
```

Based on [this](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/bellhouse/Links.pdf) it looks like your data above are actually the same, standard Bliss (1935) data set referred to in the link above.

Answer (score 4):

SAS would allow you to apply a frequency weight using a weight statement (check proc logistic on SAS help page). However, you'll need to manipulate your data somewhat:

```
  dose    died    count
1.6907       0       53
1.6907       1        6
1.7242       0       47
1.7242       1       13... etc.
```

Also, your dose variable's range is too small, causing the estimate to be too large, I'd suggest multiply it with some bigger number like 100, or even 1000 to make the coefficient and odds ratio more manageable (aka, change the unit from liter to milliliter).

---

**Question:**

I want to do the exactly the same analysis in SAS. Can anyone please help me with that? Here is what i did in SAS, but thats not working. Any idea why

```
data beetle_data;
input dose total dead;
y = dead/total;
datalines;
1.6907  59 6
1.7242  60 13
1.7552  62 18
1.7842  56 28
1.8113  63 52
1.8369  59 53
1.8610  62 61
1.8839  60 60
;

proc logistic data=beetle_data;
model y =dose/link=logit dist=binomial;
run;
```

**Answer:**

PROC LOGISTIC runs only logistic regression, unlike GLM and GENMOD you do not need to specify distribution. Here is how I'd do it, but there can be a faster way that I am not aware of.

```
data beetle_data;
input dose total dead;
y = dead/total;
datalines;
1.6907  59 6
1.7242  60 13
1.7552  62 18
1.7842  56 28
1.8113  63 52
1.8369  59 53
1.8610  62 61
1.8839  60 60
;

data beetleDead;
set beetle_data;
killed = 1;
drop total;
rename dead = beetleCount;
run;

data beetleSurvived;
set beetle_data;
killed = 0;
beetleCount = total - dead;
drop total dead;
run;

data beetleAll;
set beetleDead beetleSurvived;
run;

proc logistic data=beetleAll;
model killed = dose;
weight beetleCount;
run;
```

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks! I rechecked my code and I used odds rather than ln(odds). I have corrected my answer. However, I would not consider my last paragraph incorrect even you disagreed with the "last few" paragraphs. The current odds ratio is about 7.6x10^14, it's not conducive to interpretation.

Comment: I agree that a smaller dose unit would make interpretation easier.

Comment: Note that the real dose observations were converted to log. Would taking anti-log making the data better?

Comment: I have added the finalised code which did not work either. Would you guys mind taking a look?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, thanks, but the code produces the error 
"ERROR: Variable beetleCount not found in DATA=WORK.BEETLEALL". Did it work on your PC?

Comment: @Günal, a couple of "beetleCount" was misspelled. I've corrected them. In addition, if you found SAS flipped your coefficients, change the model statement to: `model killed (event = '1') = dose;`

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I should have seen that :) It perfectly works now. Thanks a million. I could not be more grateful.

Comment: I don't have SAS handy.  Does my (much simpler) approach work?

Comment: @BenBolker, I am terribly sorry that I had not seen your reply. It perfectly works as I desired. No need to convert the data. Much appreciated